# Can the android emulator be rooted to run python scripts as root?

Tags: android-emulator

Using the Android Scripting Environment (ASE), I can run Python scripts on the Android emulator that ships with the SDK. However, I want to run the scripts as root/superuser for some reasons, like creating log files and some more.

Like the actual phones, can the emulator be rooted to execute these scripts as root or some superuser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You always have root on the Android emulator. To prove it, open a shell and type:

```
# su
# whoami
root
```

As for running scripts as root, you can do it from a shell, but not from within ASE currently. That's tracked by [issue 184](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/issues/detail?id=184). You can star it if you'd like to be notified when that is supported.

Answer (score 0):

No, we are not root always. for security reasons, the root access has been patched by Google in the current releases.  We get root only after remounting, that too is not permanent, it vanishes when next reboot.

and "su" returns "uid not allowed to 10045".

This is in case of Emulator, but on real device, root can be gain very easily!